# Matrix defined by cartesian product of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Basic wording question:

Consider two finite and disjoint sets: A and B

If I define a Matrix M $\in \mathbb{R}^{A\times B}$  i.e assign a real to each pair of elements

Is there any special way I can refer to this matrix (wording wise) ?

I'm currently going for: "We define matrix M over the cartesian product of sets A and B such that ... (properties of M)"

Comment: Unless the sets are ordered, M doesn't have a well-defined structure. If A and B are unordered, M sounds more like a function/mapping from A x B to the reals.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't referring to any kind of special structure, I'm trying to make an abstract description of a problem and choosing the wording for it. I guess I'm going to go with a mapping.

Comment: It seems that you mean $M ∈ ℝ^{A × B}$ rather than the $ℝ^{\dim(A) × \dim(B)}$.

Comment: I think you might want to add that the set $B$ is finite; otherwise the product defined in unser87690's answer may not be well-defined (or at least the definition needs some modification).

Comment: Both are finite, disjoint sets. Added edit for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can call it a matrix. The only place when the structure of matrix matters is when you define matrix multiplication. And we have no problem here: for $M ∈ ℝ^{A × B}$ and $N ∈ ℝ^{B × C}$ we define $M · N ∈ ℝ^{A × C}$ by $(M · N)_{a c} = ∑_{b ∈ B} M_{a b} · N_{b c}$.

Also, you have a natural action of $(A × B)$-matrices on $ℝ^B$ by indetifying $ℝ^B$ with $ℝ^{B × 1}$.

**Added:** To be completely safe, we should assume that $B$ is finite. Otherwise we should use some kind of infinite sums – e.g. taking $\sup$ of finite subsums when all entries are nonnegative. Or considering infitite sums in abelian topological groups and allowing divering elements in the resulting matrix.

Comment: You should probably require, at the least, that $B$ is a finite set so that the sum makes sense.

Comment: @JohnHughes: You are right. Usually, matrices are finite, so I assumed finite sets.